# GridBagLayout Resizing Panel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have read several articles regarding this topic as well the documentation, yet I still can't seem to solve my problem.

I have created a GUI that needs to be resizeable; however, I would like to maintain that there are 3 JTextFields for each row.

I have tried adjusting the weightx, yet no success.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    JPanel panelMain = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panelMain);

    JPanel panelForm = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    panelMain.add(panelForm);

    //JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(panelForm);
    //panelMain.add(scrollpane);



    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;

    // Row 1
    buttonAddCourses = new JButton("Add Credit Hours");
    buttonAddCourses.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            c.gridx = 0;
            c.weightx = 0.2;
            for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                JTextField newTextField = new JTextField(20);
                listTextFields.add(newTextField);
                panelMain.add(newTextField,c);
                c.gridy++;

            }

            panelMain.validate();
            panelMain.repaint();
        }

    });
    panelForm.add(buttonAddCourses, c);
    c.gridx++;
```

Before Resize : !https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRQUf.jpg

After Resize : 
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBePZ.jpg

Comment: Please create and post a valid [mcve]

Comment: `I have created a GUI that needs to be resizeable; however, I would like to maintain that there are 3 JTextFields for each row.` -  A GridBagLayout does not "wrap" components to a new row based on the space available. Resizing will never change the number of components in a row. It will only resize the components. You requirement really isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
JPanel panelMain = new JPanel(); // <- gets a FlowLayout by default
// ..
JPanel panelForm = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); // panel with GBL
// ...
    panelMain.add(newTextField,c); // No, this should be panelForm.add(..);
```